# Row-wise mean imputation in R

Tags: r, statistics, null

Someone on SO asked how to fill in the NA's with row means. His example code was:

> ```
> cancer1 <- read.table("cancer.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote='', header=TRUE,sep='\t')
> ```

Since he didn't provide the data I think we can simulate it with:

> ```
> cancer1 <- data.frame(a=rep(c(1,2,3,NA),10),b=rep(c(1,2,3,4),10), c=seq(1,40,1))
> ```

Just bear in mind that the example data is an arbitrary simulation.

My answer was:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(cancer1)){
  for(n in 1:ncol(cancer1)){
    if(is.na(cancer1[i,n])){
        cancer1[i,n]  <-  mean(t(cancer1[i,]), na.rm = T)# or  rowMeans(cancer1[i,], na.rm=T)
    }
    }
}
```

I know that this can be vectorized and otherwise improved, but I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rowMeans` with indexing.

```
k <- which(is.na(cancer1), arr.ind=TRUE)
cancer1[k] <- rowMeans(cancer1, na.rm=TRUE)[k[,1]]
```

Where `k` is an indices of the rows with `NA` values.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is late. Alternatively, you  could use `!complete.cases()` in place `is.na()` to retrieve the rows that have `NA` values. I use `rowMeans` just like [m0nhawk](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/134193/103677) and stored the values in a `data.frame` . I also swapped the `NA` column with the values from the `data.frame`.

```
cancer1 <- data.frame(a=rep(c(1,2,3,NA),10),b=rep(c(1,2,3,4),10), c=seq(1,40,1))
d<- data.frame(mean=rowMeans(cancer1[!complete.cases(cancer1),], na.rm=TRUE))
cancer1[!complete.cases(cancer1),1]<-d
```

I hope this helps.